# Connected property of R: Least element of a set not containing its infimum???

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have this issue I am trying to understand.  I am trying to think about the smallest positive real number (which I know perfectly well does not exist) but it keeps making my brain explode. I am certain one million people before me have wondered about the same thing, so I am making this post seeking:

- Better language with which I might describe the issue.
- Any concise references that discuss the issue I'm getting at.
- Any insights you all might have on why, perhaps, the issue is not the problem it seems to me to be.

Here is the issue:  Consider the connected real unit interval $[0,1]$ in the usual topology.  Let it be decomposed as

$$ U=\{0\}~~,\qquad\text{and}\qquad V=(0,1]~~.$$

If the unit interval is connected, which it most certainly is, then $U$ must have some element of $V$ immediately to its right.  However, since $V$ is half open on the $U$ side, every element of $V$ has an open $\delta$-neighborhood lying totally within $V$.  If every element of $V$ has more elements of $V$ to its left, then no element of $V$ can lie immediately to the right of $U$.

So... please see that my question is not really about the smallest positive number.  Rather, my question regards the connectedness of real intervals.  If $U\cup V$ is connected, then what is $U$ connected to?  If it's not connected to anything, as it seems not to be, then what is some better language I can use to think about the issue?

Comment: How do jump from “the unit interval is connected” to “$U$ must have some element of $V$ immediately to its right”?

Comment: If there was something between $U$ and $V$, then $U\cup V$ would seem not to be connected.

Comment: Wrong. There is nothing between $U$ and $V$ and nevertheless $U\cup V$ is connected.

Comment: You are being unjust: @JoséCarlosSantos is telling it like it is. There is no element of $V$ "right-adjacent" to $U$. This is not pedantic scolding, it is mathematics. Get used to it.

Comment: Nice claim you have there @TonyK.  Try proving it.

Comment: Oh Jimmy, do you really think you know better than 150 years of the world's finest mathematicians?

Comment: If you're aware of some proof that has been given, then why not share it instead of posing a question whose answer is not related to the topic of the thread?   Riddle me that, @TonyK.

Comment: So you're not aware of any proof of your claim then?  Or you just prefer scolding over sharing?

Comment: You seem to be unaware of the topic of this thread, and you certainly did not read the first two sentences of my question.  Maybe you'd be better off PMing your interesting thoughts directly to José and leaving me out of it?

Comment: But your putative element of $V$ "right-adjacent" to $U$ would obviously have to be the smallest strictly positive real number. Which doesn't exist. There's my proof!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the better way to speak of it is precisely with the notion of neighborhoods (which I suppose is what you're using since you're talking about connectedness).

Rather than the imprecise '$U$ must have some element of $V$ immediately to its right', you should say that any neighborhood of $U$ (ie, any open set containing $U$) intersects $V$.
This gives the notion that no matter how little you 'enlarge' $U$, you still bump into $V$, without running into the nonsense that inevitably arises from thinking about taking a 'smallest', but positive, step.

---

I think these kinds of questions generally benefit from thinking in terms of 'arbitrarily small' rather than 'smallest'.

And similarly for infinity, thinking in terms of 'arbitrarily large' rather than 'largest'.

Answer (score 1):

For I = [0,1] to be disconnected requires
two disjoint open sets whose union is I.

The disjoint U and V you presented does not make I
disconnected because only one of them is open.

There is no such thing as a point immediately to
the right of any closed sets including U.

Though there is a point immediately to the right
of [0,1), namely 1, it obscures the point that 1
is in the closure of [0,1), a boundary point.

Comment: What would be a good way (the BEST way) for me to describe in mathematical terms the smallest subset of $[0,1)$ that has $\{1\}$ immediately to the right of it?  The problem I have is that no matter how much I shrink the interval, it still has infinitely many points in it.  Is there any workaround?

Comment: How do you define smallest?

Comment: Call it the set with the least cardinality, one I'm hoping I can get down to something less than infinity.

Comment: That's a weird definition. In any case, any finite subset of $[0,1)$ has positive distance to $\{1\}$, so no bueno.

Comment: Moreover, what does it mean to have '$\{1\}$ immediately to the right' of a set (especially when a set has holes, like any countable or finite set)? I suspect we're going back to $\sup$s.

Answer (score 0):

$U,V$ do not decompose $[0,1]$ to contradict connectedness as $U \cap \overline{V} \neq \emptyset$, as $0$ lies in the closure of $(0,1]$ (any open neighbourhood of $0$ intersects $V$).

In a disconnection $U$, $V$ of a space we must have either $U$ and $V$ both open, or both closed and in both cases we have that $U$ and $V$ are separated, i.e. $U \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset$ and $V \cap \overline{U} = \emptyset$. All three possibilities fail: $U=\{0\}$ is not open, but *is* closed, $V=(0,1]$ is open but not closed and they are not separated as we already saw.